# Drawing circumference issue

Tags: geometry, circles, analytic-geometry

I'm a developer, and I'm developing an app on Google Maps. At the moment, I'm trying to draw a circle on the map.

For getting all the points I need, I'm using the following formula:

\begin{equation}
y=y_c\pm\sqrt{r^2-(x-x_c)^2}
\end{equation}

but I get an ellipse, not a circle.

[image]

Did I mistake the formula?

Or I need to search the error in my code?

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE
I found that I have to draw an ellipse, because of the different axis scale.
At the moment I can find four correct points (north, east, south, west).

Comment: At 45 degrees north longitude lines are much closer together than latitude lines.  Perhaps this is what is compressing your circle horizontally.

Comment: A problem that also Andreas Blass noticed. I suppose that now I need to work with an ellipse.
I have an update: I can get four points (north, south, east, west) and they are all correct.
Now, can I get the right equation of the ellipse, by using these four points? Do I need more or less points?

Comment: You have enough with three points, giving the center and the half-axis lengths. $\frac1{a^2}(x-x_c)^2+\frac1{b^2}(y-y_c)^2=1$.

Comment: This is also relevant: [Discretize a circle on a sphere with a given center and radius](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/327699/139123) (but it may be more than you need for your application).

Comment: About the last comment, yes, maybe it's something more. I will try your formula, I suppose I have to solve a system of three of these equations. I will put the center, and two other points I found.

Comment: @YvesDaoust
I solved my problem thanks to your formula (and a little of Wolfram Alpha...)!
I found this solving formula:
\begin{equation}
y_{1,2}=\frac {ay_c\pm b\sqrt{a^2-(x-x_c)^2}}{a}
\end{equation}
and now I get the right ellipse.
Edit your answer and I will give you the point.

Comment: @studente100: do you mean that I must copy the formula ?

Comment: No no, just edit your answer suggesting your formula, the one you wrote yesterday.

Answer (score 2):

One way to accidentally get an ellipse instead of a circle is to have different length scales on the two coordinate axes.

Answer (score 1):

Google Maps uses the Mercator projection system, which distorts the coordinates vertically, proportionally to the **secant of the latitude**.

On the picture I measure that the ellipse is about $482\times689$ pixels, i.e. has an aspect ratio of $0.7$, which corresponds to a latitude of $45.6°$. The true latitude of Milano is $45°28'=45.46°$. Not so bad...

Answer (score 0):

The general equation of an circle is $(x-x_c)^2+(y-y_c)^2=r^2$. This can be rewritten to your equation. I think that there is a mistake in your code. In particular, check whether you don't divide of multiply $x$ by anything, that will result in an ellipse.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much. I will check and let you know.