# Circumfrence to diameter ratio of a Circle scribed on a sphere?

Tags: pi, spherical-geometry

On the face of it this might just seem silly, but I wonder if I scribe a circle on a sphere will the ratio of the circumference of such a circle to its diameter would still be $\pi$. If so, is there a way I could prove it or disprove otherwise?

Comment: I'd like to know how are you inscribing a circle on a sphere?

Comment: @Shraddheya Shendre: I edited my question to replace inscribe by scribe.

Comment: Do you intend to discretize a circle on a sphere? [This question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/327699/discretize-a-circle-on-a-sphere-with-a-given-center-and-radius) might be of interest to you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you're trying to stick to quantities measured on the surface of the sphere, right? In that case, you're basically working with [spherical trigonometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_trigonometry). In this particular case, the 'radius' of the circle corresponds to a central (polar) angle of the sphere using the standard arc length formula:
$$s = \theta R$$ if $R$ is the sphere's radius, $\theta$ is the angle, and $s$ is the circle's "radius".

Finding the arc length of the circle is a straightforward exercise in $3$-$d$ geometry (or integration of the line element) that gives:
$$C = 2\pi R \sin\theta,$$ leading to:
$$\begin{align}
\frac{C}{D} & = \frac{C}{2s} \\
& = \pi \frac{\sin \theta}{\theta}. \\
& = \pi \frac{R \sin\left(\frac{s}{R}\right)}{s} \\
& \approx \pi \left( 1 + \frac{1}{3!} \left[\frac{s}{R}\right]^2 + \ldots\right)
\end{align}$$

So, in a non-Euclidean geometry, if you define $\pi$ in terms of the ratio of circumference to diameter of a circle you get an answer that depends on the diameter of the circle. That's not how it's commonly used, though, since the value of $\pi$ is so useful outside of geometry. You can consider $\pi$ to be defined as:
$$\pi \equiv \lim_{D\rightarrow0} \frac{C}{D},$$ in all sufficiently smooth spaces, or just define it in terms of one of the mathematical series.

If the [Gaussian curvature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_curvature) is negative, but still constant everywhere, then the space is hyperbolic, and the $R$ in the circumference formulae becomes imaginary, giving:
$$C = 2\pi R \sinh \left(\frac{s}{R}\right).$$

You can do similar exercises concerning the sum of the angles of a triangle to prove that they add up to some value that depends on the size of the triangle in these non-Euclidean spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Any circle satisfies the condition that the ratio of its circumference to its diameter is $\pi$, so yes.